# Which raspberry pi nowadays is compatible with 32bit ARMv7 assembly code?

Tags: arm, assembly

I'm taking an assembly code class in college, and we're going to study ARM assembly. However, we'll only cover 32bit ARMv7 assembly code.

The class uses some weird ARM emulator, but I would much rather program in bare metal.

And I've heard that Raspberry Pis use ARM chips, and I've been meaning to get one for a while now, so this situation seemed like a perfect opportunity to get one.

However, I've been looking around Raspberry Pi's website, and I wasn't able to find a Raspberry Pi board which used 32bit ARMv7 architecture

FYI: I am VERY new to the whole assembly world, so maybe there exists some "equivalent" to 32bit ARMv7.

Is there a board that would serve my purpose?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Model_comparison

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, I don't see any mention of CPU architecture/Compatibility in said chart

Comment: If you read through the whole page it does show which models contain which SOC and thus those with an ARM7 or ARM8 core - basically all since Pi2. Mind you most Raspberry Pi OS use an ARM6 kernel and your actual question is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is, and I'm asking because I sincerely do not know. Will I be able to code ARM assembly code on a ARMv8 that could run on a ARMv7 chip?
Does that compatibily exist?

Comment: I have read that ARM is backwards compatible, does that apply to 64 bit Chip as well?
Will 32-bit ARMv7 code work on a 64-bit ARMv8 machine?

Comment: The 64 bit SOC run ARM7 & ARM6 code - indeed ALL the Raspberry Pi OS  32 bit applications are ARM6

Comment: Oh! Then in that case any "newer" raspberry pi should work then! Right? If so then I'll give it a spin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an assembly programmer, but the only model with a 32-bit ARMv7 core is the Pi 2.  Unfortunately right now they are going to be [hard to find](https://www.rpilocator.com/) and expensive (eg., while there are none on that current "rpi locator" board, they are available on amazon.ca with no accessories for $172 CDN, ~4x their original price, with a 2 week delivery time...).

However, there are a number of different [ARMv7-A implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Armv7-A_processors), and if you click through the right column, for some of them there you will find lists of SoCs that use them, [eg. for Cortex-A9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A9#Systems_on_a_chip).

Probably a good option is the [BeagleBoard Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black).  The original price was slightly higher than a comparable Pi, and while they look to be subject to similar market forces/logistical issues, they are only about twice that on amazon.ca.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer! So in theory, every single chip in that Wikipedia list should work with the same Assembly code. Correct?

Comment: Again, I'm not an assembly programmer, but I do know from compiling C/C++ and such that what is spit out targets an ISA; there are more specific tweaks, eg., ARMv6 has a series of progressive variants that add functionality and were incorporated into ARMv7, meaning you have something like ARMv6 1/2 (it's not referred to that way, just a illustrative analogy) and ARMv6 3/4, but anything for baseline ARMv6 will work there.

Comment: ...Also, if you look at the various linux distros that have binary releases for ARMv7 etc, they are usable on any system that implements that.  Currently, I think (almost) all the distros that work on the Pi are that -- they are compiled for whatever ARM version generally, *except for* (maybe, dunno for sure) Raspbian/RPi OS -- which, in any case, started out as a binary fork of Debian for ARMv6 (by "binary fork" I mean it was not specially compiled, but more or less window dressing on a pre-existing,pre-compiled Debian), and in fact was that for most of Pi history (if it isn't still so).